# script fails to run with no such file or directory

Tags: shell, unix, docker, permissions

I created a docker image which ends with running a script to configure my container on startup.

Part of docker file which execute script is like below

```
RUN chmod +x /scratch/software/config/config.sh 
CMD /scratch/software/config/config.sh
```

The script looks like below

```
echo "Starting WLS"
whoami
echo $DOMAIN_HOME
cd $DOMAIN_HOME
pwd
ls -ltr ./bin/
sh ./bin/startWeblogic.sh 
tail -f -n0 /etc/hosts
```

those whoami pwd etc are just for debugging purpose. The output is:

```
Starting WLS
root
/scratch/software/Oracle/Middleware/Wls122120/user_projects/domains/fa_domain
/scratch/software/Oracle/Middleware/Wls122120/user_projects/domains/fa_domain
total 108
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 Feb 11 07:22 service_migration
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 Feb 11 07:22 server_migration
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 Feb 11 07:22 patching
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 Feb 11 07:22 nodemanager
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  2166 Feb 11 07:27 stopWebLogic.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root   889 Feb 11 07:27 stopRSDaemon.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  1153 Feb 11 07:27 stopNodeManager.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  2699 Feb 11 07:27 stopManagedWebLogic.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  1985 Feb 11 07:27 stopComponent.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  7211 Feb 11 07:27 startWebLogic.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root   725 Feb 11 07:27 startRSDaemon.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  1832 Feb 11 07:27 startNodeManager.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  2928 Feb 11 07:27 startManagedWebLogic.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  2321 Feb 11 07:27 startComponent.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 21083 Feb 11 07:27 setStartupEnv.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root   925 Feb 11 07:27 setNMJavaHome.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 14566 Feb 11 07:27 setDomainEnv.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  2675 Feb 11 07:27 generateArchive.sh
sh: ./bin/startWeblogic.sh: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure why it says no such file or directory

Comment: Capital `l`?  As such: `startWeblogic.sh` vs `startWebLogic.sh`

Comment: could not believe it is such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, the script calls `sh ./bin/startWeblogic.sh` where `startWeblogic` has no capital on `logic`, while in the listing of files you have `startWebLogic`.

Comment: one of the silliest mistake

Comment: Probably you can delete your question.